# SMS Server / Gateway

Tags: sms

Im anxious to know how can I send free bulk sms messages through the web. Are there any free services out there or can I build one on a machine that's connected to the internet?
Will local telephone companies, as receivers, tax me for sending messages?

Thanks.

Comment: so, what is your question ?? you want to setup some server for sending sms??

Comment: Actually, I've merged 3 questions inside this post. I'd like to setup a server for sending sms, but I think I need to get some answers first.

Comment: you will get the answer, once your question is clear for you and others. So be specific.

Comment: I've updated the question, please take a look now.

Comment: as per my knowledge, i have updated one post, have a look, it is helpful, then don't forget to accept it.

Comment: your wish is my command, master. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to send SMS messages free, and it turned out, that recently in several countries the mobile network operators have updated their pricing policy to offer unlimited SMS messages in some data plans. In some cases unlimited messages are not available, but they don't charge anything for the first two or three thousand SMS messages sent per month. These data plans are available for standard mobile phone subscriptions, but they can also be used if you have setup an [Ozeki NG SMS Gateway](http://www.ozekisms.com/) system on your computer.

You can use this opportunity to build interesting solutions, for example you can send SMS from your database, or from Microsoft Excel, Outlook, etc. Check out these documents:

1. [Send SMS from a database](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=164)
2. [Excel SMS](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=466)
3. [Outlook SMS](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=383)